# Producing a string that rotates a letter with each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

My task is to use javascript and jquery to produce a web page that takes a user-submitted string and produces that string as such: `abcde` => `bcdea`  my problem is that when I try and run the program there is no output. I check the error console and it says rotate is not define. I'm just very confused.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- This page demonstrates several string properties and operations -->
<!-- =============================================================== --> 

<html>
<head>  
  <title> String Demo </title> 
  <script  src="..111/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function rotate(s)
    {
      result = $('#strBox').value;              
      "rotate:" + result
      var result = "";
      for (var i = 0; i< s.length; ++i){
        result = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);
        $('#outputDiv').innerHTML = 
      }
    }
  </script>
  </script>
</head> 

<body> 
  <h2>String Demo</h2>  
  <p>
    Enter a string: <input type="text" id="strBox" size=20 value="">
  </p>
  <input type="button" value="Click to Process" onclick="rotate();">                   
  <hr>
  <div id="outputDiv"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the problem is ....

Comment: You don't say what the problem is, but one problem I can see is that the `rotate()` function expects a parameter (`s`) that is used within the function, but when you call it you don't pass a value. Also the last line of the function is incomplete: `$('#outputDiv').innerHTML =` you need to assign it equal to something - except that jQuery objects don't have an `innerHTML` property, so that would simply create one and you'd never see the value displayed on screen.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the jQuery documentation regarding the DOM innerHTML property and then consider the line: `$('#outputDiv').innerHTML`

Comment: `result = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);` seems okay, but pretty much every other line in your function is either pointless or has problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
function rotate(s)
{
  result = $('#strBox').value;
```

Looks like it creates a global variable, but you declare it lower down. Better to declare variables at the top, or at least when first used.

```
  var result = $('#strBox').value;
```

`$(<selector>)` returns a jQuery object. You are getting the value of the `value` property of that object, likely you want the value of the selected element (if it has one). Since jQuery wraps elements, you need to call a function to access properties:

```
  var result = $('#strBox').val();
```

.

```
  "rotate:" + result
```

The equivalent of an empty statement, the result is not assigned so has no effect.

```
  var result = "";
```

Ah, there's that pesky declaration. The assignment happens later.

```
  for (var i = 0; i< s.length; ++i){
    result = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);
```

This will loop over the string once for each character, so you end up with the string you started with.

```
    $('#outputDiv').innerHTML =
```

jQuery doesn't have an `innerHTML` property, DOM objects do. Again, jQuery needs a method to do property access. And you need to actually assign a value, so:

```
    $('#outputDiv').html(result);
```

or

```
    $('#outputDiv').text(result);
  }
}
```

But since browsers wait for scripts to stop running before updating the DOM, you won't see anything change (it would likely only be a blur anyway).

What you may want is something like:

```
<script>

function rotate(element) {
  var s = element.form.strBox.value;
  document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);
}
</script>

<form>
  <p>Enter a string: <input type="text" name="strBox" size=20 value="">
  <p><input type="button" value="Click to Process" onclick="rotate(this);">                   
</form>  
<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Note that using a form makes accessing form controls easier as they are available as named properties of the form.

Comment: Your answer is the right kind for situations like this. +1

Answer (score 0):

1. the function "rotate" takes a parameter that is not used.

   function rotate(s)
   {
2. result is not defined as a variable for another two lines.  Value is not a property of the jQuery object.

   ```
   result = $('#strBox').value;
   ```
3. The text "rotate:" + result is not be assigned to a variable and there is no semicolon

   ```
   "rotate:" + result

   var result = "";
   ```
4. This loop is not necessary, just take the first character from the string, remove it, and add it to the end of the string.

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i< s.length; ++i){
       result = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);
   ```
5. "innerHTML" is not a valid property of the jQuery object.  And the value isn't being assigned to anything.

   ```
       $('#outputDiv').innerHTML = 
   }
   ```

   }